# What username/credentials are used to do File read/write operation using servlet?

Tags: servlets, file-io

I am writing and reading image file to a directory using servlet. I want to know if the servlet uses appserver credentials to read/write from folder or is it something else ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reading/writing you need that the process which runs the application server has OS priviledges to write/read from directory/file.